# CSS: transparent part of border line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div which look like this.

[image]

```css
.triangle-area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.triangle1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 50px 50px 0 50px;
  border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.triangle2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  border-width: 50px 50px 50px 0;
  right: 0;
  border-color: transparent blue transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.triangle3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 0 50px 50px 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.triangle4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  border-width: 50px 0 50px 50px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent yellow;
  border-style: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-area">
  <div class="triangle1"></div>
  <div class="triangle2"></div>
  <div class="triangle3"></div>
  <div class="triangle4"></div>
</div>
```

But how to let transparent part of each border line not overlapping each other?
I need to make each triangle div as a button with hover, when I add hover to it, it will color the entire border line instead of just the colored part.

[image]

Comment: Could you please expand more on what hover/click functionality you are trying to achieve. I added below how you can achieve the pattern you are looking for however I'm not certain on how you want the interactive element to function.

Comment: @MattDavis I need to make each border line able to hover and be clickable for different functions, so I separate into 4 divs

Answer (score 0):

If a clickable image is acceptable then you can use a map:
(I've only added the area for yellow for simplicity)

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHJNY.png" usemap="#my-links">
<map name="my-links">
  <area id="yellow" shape="polygon" coords="0,0,50,50,50,100,0,150" href="https://www.teamtrees.org/">
</map>
```

Comment: I need to make each border line able to hover, so I separate into 4 divs

Comment: @hatched is a clickable image acceptable or will it need to be dynamically sized?

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add one more style for each div with the hover attribute, for example:

```
.triangle1:hover {
  border-color: orange;
}
```

if you want to give it more complex functionality, you must add an id and control it with javascript

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to change the color of every single colored border and keep the transparent border of the div transparent as they are. And then you want to make it clickable or add some function or event on it.

If it is, then you can try by adding this code in your css...

```
/* to change the red color to grey on hover */
.triangle1:hover {
  border-color: grey transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* to change the blue color to grey on hover*/
.triangle2:hover {
  border-color: transparent blue transparent transparent;
}
/* to change the green color to grey on hover*/
.triangle3:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
}
/* to change the yellow color to grey on hover*/
.triangle4:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent yellow;
}
```

And next, if you want to add event or function to onclick of it. Then add **id** to use it on javascript. Or add onclick function directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `clip-path` for this. Here is a basic idea where it's also responsive:

```css
.container {
  margin:20px;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}
.container > div:nth-child(1),
.container > div:nth-child(2){
   position:absolute;
   height:25%;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   background:red;
   clip-path:polygon(0 0, 100% 0,80% 100%,20% 100%);
}
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
  bottom:0;
  top:auto;
  transform:scaleY(-1);
  background:blue;
}

.container > div:nth-child(3),
.container > div:nth-child(4){
   position:absolute;
   width:20%;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   background:green;
   clip-path:polygon(0 0, 100% 25%,100% 75%,0 100%);
}
.container > div:nth-child(4) {
  right:0;
  left:auto;
  transform:scaleX(-1);
  background:purple;
}

.container > div:hover {
  filter:grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

In case you want to keep the same width/height of the element you can update like below:

```css
.container {
  margin:20px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
}
.container > div:nth-child(1),
.container > div:nth-child(2){
   position:absolute;
   height:50px;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   background:red;
   clip-path:polygon(0 0, 100% 0,calc(100% - 50px) 100%,50px 100%);
}
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
  bottom:0;
  top:auto;
  transform:scaleY(-1);
  background:blue;
}

.container > div:nth-child(3),
.container > div:nth-child(4){
   position:absolute;
   width:50px;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   background:green;
   clip-path:polygon(0 0, 100% 50px,100% calc(100% - 50px),0 100%);
}
.container > div:nth-child(4) {
  right:0;
  left:auto;
  transform:scaleX(-1);
  background:purple;
}

.container > div:hover {
  filter:grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```